# Can I access Visual Studio Debugger’s autos information in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a setup at work where we absolutely CANNOT debug our server code. I want to write a method so when called, it logs all the variables names and values from the scope of the call site like how autos and locals windows work. Is this possible? I know I can get local variable names through reflection and debug api, but I don’t know about their values.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2022

Comment: @HansPassant I said we cannot debug our server code

Comment: What are you trying to do? Debug code running on a server? That's generally not possible (no network admin is going to allow a debugger to reach into a server and attach to a running process). You could install a debugger on the server (pick something lighter than VS if you can) and debug from there - but that's still a bad idea. Normally, if you _really_ need to debug a server resident process, you take dump(s) and use post-mortem debugging tools and techniques

Comment: For the third time, I am not debugging the server. I have said I cannot do that. 

I am looking for any sort of reflection on runtime debug libraries to be able to log dump things in a way similar to autos or local like vs debug.

Comment: It is what you will end up doing, eventually.

Comment: Not in places where it isn’t allowed

Comment: You can indeed use reflection to inspect the state of the stack frame that called the method. But reflection will kill performance. So you can directly use [log4net](https://blog.elmah.io/log4net-tutorial-the-complete-guide-for-beginners-and-pros/) to log variables.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is possible to get the values runtime, to me better approach would be to use logging frameworks like log4net, Serilog, NLog etc. in your code to capture required variable name and values within any function you want. You might need to setup debug flag (which can be 'on' based on your demand) to log information like this otherwise logs would be use.